# Count ngram word frequency using text collocations

Tags: python, nltk, collocation

I would like to count the frequency of three words preceding and following a specific word from a text file which has been converted into tokens.

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.util import ngrams
with open('dracula.txt', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as textfile:
    text_data = textfile.read().replace('\n', ' ').lower()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text_data)
text = nltk.Text(tokens)
grams = nltk.ngrams(tokens, 4)
freq = Counter(grams)
freq.most_common(20)
```

I don't know how to search for the string 'dracula' as a filter word. I also tried:

```
text.collocations(num=100)
text.concordance('dracula')
```

The desired output would look something like this with counts:
Three words preceding 'dracula', sorted count

```
(('and', 'he', 'saw', 'dracula'), 4),
(('one', 'cannot', 'see', 'dracula'), 2)
```

Three words following 'dracula', sorted count

```
(('dracula', 'and', 'he', 'saw'), 4),
(('dracula', 'one', 'cannot', 'see'), 2)
```

The trigram containing 'dracula' in the middle, sorted count

```
(('count', 'dracula', 'saw'), 4),
(('count', 'dracula', 'cannot'), 2)
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get the frequency information in tuple format, as you've done, you can simply filter out the word you're looking for with `if` statements. This is using Python's *list comprehension* syntax:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.util import ngrams

with open('dracula.txt', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as textfile:
    text_data = textfile.read().replace('\n', ' ').lower()
    # pulled text from here: https://archive.org/details/draculabr00stokuoft/page/n6

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text_data)
text = nltk.Text(tokens)
grams = nltk.ngrams(tokens, 4)
freq = nltk.Counter(grams)

dracula_last = [item for item in freq.most_common() if item[0][3] == 'dracula']
dracula_first = [item for item in freq.most_common() if item[0][0] == 'dracula']
dracula_second = [item for item in freq.most_common() if item[0][1] == 'dracula']
# etc.
```

This produces lists with "dracula" in different positions. Here is what `dracula_last` looks like:

```
[(('the', 'castle', 'of', 'dracula'), 3),
 (("'s", 'journal', '243', 'dracula'), 1),
 (('carpathian', 'moun-', '2', 'dracula'), 1),
 (('of', 'the', 'castle', 'dracula'), 1),
 (('named', 'by', 'count', 'dracula'), 1),
 (('disease', '.', 'count', 'dracula'), 1),
 ...]
```

Comment: Thanks, I just had to modify the last one and change the ngram tokens to 3 for it to become a trigram.